# Convert String to Int/int64/Decimal?

Tags: string, type-conversion, int, decimal

I'm actually using a module from HP that get's the BIOS version of a system.  It was easy to convert a string to an integer on some systems because it only had one decimal point.  But now I'm running into some systems that has BIOS version with two decimal points and I can no longer use [int] or [decimal] or [double] etc..

So if I have string that has a value of "02.01.06" and I try to change that type to an integer, it fails to do so. 
Example:

```
[int]$InstalledBiosVersion = Get-HPBiosVersion
```

Cannot convert value "02.01.06" to type "System.Int32". Error: "Input string was not in a correct format.

I need to change the string to an integer because I'm comparing bios versions that installed on the system(s) to what is the latest version available. So if one number is -lt the other, the bios is out of date.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

Never mind, I ended up just removing the two digits and the . and then converting it to a decimal.

```
[decimal]$InstalledBiosVersion = (Get-HPBiosVersion).Remove(0,4)
```